# followupEvent not matching any intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment) to implement the backend of my service based on dialogflow. There's a point where I use the method `agent.setFollowupEvent(targetIntent)`, the `targetIntent` requires a context to be matchable, let's call it `targetContext`.

I can't tell exactly when it stopped working (a week? month maybe?), but it worked and right now it's not working (and I don't think I've changed anything that could explain it). The `targetIntent` fulfillment never get called and I can see in the dialogflow console that it's because the request triggered by `setFollowupEvent` doesn't match any intent.

If I remove the requirement of the `targetContext` from the `targetIntent`, it works.

I think I'm setting the context correctly:

```
agent.context.set(targetContext, null, null);
agent.setFollowupEvent(targetIntent);
```

Inspecting the body of the response that *dialogflow-fulfillment* is sending to dialogflow I see:

```
{
    "outputContexts": [{ "name": "projects/<myprojectid>/agent/sessions/<mysessionid>/contexts/<targetContext>" }],
    "followupEventInput": { "name": "<targetIntent>", "languageCode": "it" }
}
```

The context is there, and I think is correct.
Any clues? The only thing I can think of is that we changed the agent type from free to enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, I've found the solution just after asking the question...

The problem was the lifespan of the context, I did not set it, now it works with:

```
                                 |
                                 V
agent.context.set(targetContext, 1, null);
agent.setFollowupEvent(targetIntent);
```

So the output become:

```
{
    "outputContexts": [{ "name": "projects/<myprojectid>/agent/sessions/<mysessionid>/contexts/<targetContext>", "lifespanCount": 1 }],
    "followupEventInput": { "name": "<targetIntent>", "languageCode": "it" }
}
```

Still I'm quite sure it worked before, maybe not setting the lifespan used to default to 1?